# PoEdit and XML-attributes

Tags: xml, localization, poedit

I am trying to get localization running under windows by using poedit.
So far everything is fine.
Unfortunately I do have XML-files which require some attributes to be translated.
Example:

```
<CMD ID="MK">
    <SETUP_NAME NAME="Set active setting">
    <TAG_NAME>TAG_SET_ACTIVE_SETTING</TAG_NAME>
        <TAG_ID>0241</TAG_ID>
        <TAG_TYPE>FORMAT_SHORT</TAG_TYPE>
            <NO_OF_ELEMENTS>1</NO_OF_ELEMENTS>
            <ELEMENT>
                <VAL_TYPE>word</VAL_TYPE>
                <DESCRIPTION>The currently used setting</DESCRIPTION>
                <MIN_VAL>1</MIN_VAL>
                <MAX_VAL>19</MAX_VAL>
            </ELEMENT>
            <TAG_AVAILABLE>true</TAG_AVAILABLE>
        </SETUP_NAME>
```

I want to translate the attribute content of NAME of the tag SETUP_NAME.
I could not figure out how to get this running. Extracting the content of the tags works fine.

Any help is appreciated!

Regards,

Zett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the xgettext `-a, --extract-all` flag to extract all quoted strings in your XML file.

In POEdit, create a new parser that looks for XML files:

Under *Preferences*, go to the *Parsers* tab and hit *New*. Then enter:

Language:

```
XML
```

List of extensions separated by semicolons:

```
*.xml
```

Parser command:

```
xgettext -LC --extract-all -o %o %C %F
```

An item in keywords list: - leave empty

Item in input files list:

```
%f
```

source code charset:

```
--from-code=%c
```

And hit *OK*.

Make sure you add the path where your XML lives to you PO file propeties and you should be able to run *Catalogue > Update from sources*

This should forcefully extract any quoted strings into your PO file.